# Show object in an activity

Tags: java, android, object, android-activity

I just started Android development so this may be a quite easy question.

What I write at the moment is a quiz app. So I wrote the class `Frage` and now I want to display the question and three answers in an activity. Each question has an `id` so when I press a button I want to show the next question.

I think I need one `TextView` and three `buttons` for the answers. 
But how can I display the values of my object in view??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [`setText(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to display your item. Since `Button` inherits from `TextView` the methods work the same way in both cases.

Usage would look something like this:

```
myButton.setText(myObject.answerOne);
```

Comment: Great, thanks. So easy. Will accept your answer when possible! Thanks!

Comment: That's how you do it. I just want to point out that if you're only going to be displaying a Frage object in your Activity you might want to look into making this object Parcelable so you can pass it to you Activity and make it re-usable.

Answer (score 0):

Objects getter and setter methods will get you the required value. 
As far as object is concened you shouid override the

```
toString()
```

method.